# Form não passa dados via POST

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
<html>
<form name="sai_frm_incl_patr" method="post" action="sai_incl_peri_seri_patr.php">
    <body>  
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="Silver" align="center">    
            <b><font face="arial" color="blue" size="2">Inclusão de Patrimônio e serial</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="id_pat" name="w_patr_seri"  value="aaaaa">                 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

E na pagina que esta recebendo os dados eu faço isso:

```
<?php
$w_patr = trim($_POST['w_patr_seri']); 
?>
```

Mas a variável não contem nenhum conteúdo! O'que deve ser o erro? Ou o'que estou fazendo de errado?'

Comment: @TiagoSilva, já tentei dessa maneira' mas mesmo assim não funciona =/

Comment: Cara, como você esta enviando este form??? pelo que eu vi, você não tem nenhum submit pra esse form, e o input dele é hidden... ja olhou se os dados estão sendo enviados pelo firebug?

Answer (score 5):

> Tu abriu e fechou o `form` fora do `body`

```
    <html>
       <body>
            <form name="sai_frm_incl_patr" method="post" action="sai_incl_peri_seri_patr.php"> 
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="Silver" align="center">    
                    <b><font face="arial" color="blue" size="2">Inclusão de Patrimônio e serial</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="id_pat" name="w_patr_seri"  value="aaaaa">                 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </body>   
    </html>
```

Comment: Realmente @MarcosVinicius eu estava abrindo e fechando o form errado'. Mas mesmo assim ele não reconhece o post no proximo programa!

Comment: Esse `POST` tem que ser disparado de um botão, você não colocou nesse formulário um botão, como está enviando `POST`?

Comment: eu não coloquei no exemplo que coloquei aqui no pt!

Comment: Recoloca o formulário completo como **atualizado** no fundo da sua pergunta inicial sem descaracterizar o que já colocou. Assim poderemos chegar a uma resposta.